# Meaning of "a century old if it was a day"

Tags: meaning

In Ray Bradbury's *Fahrenheit 451*, there is the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> It was a flaking three-story house in the ancient part of the city, **a century old if it was a day**, but like all houses it had been given a thin fireproof plastic sheath many years ago, and this preservative seemed to be the only thing holding it in the sky.

I am not quite sure of what the bold part means. I understand it as *a building that is a century old, but in good condition thanks to some preservative*.

Is that a correct understanding of this sentence ?

Comment: No, it means "there is **no doubt** that it was at least a century old [if not longer]", by analogy to the fact that there's zero doubt that it's at least a day old. Just looking at <whatever>, you know it's *old*. Kinda like "is the Pope Catholic?". No doubt exists, so you can use it draw an analogy to some other situation where no doubt exists.

Comment: I don't think it is an exact duplicate, since sturrockad asked about the origin of the phrase without explaining its meaning, whereas the meaning is precisely what I am asking. However, [rogermue's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/256964/170145) is exactly what I was looking for. So, could someone more experienced than me tell what is the procedure to follow? Mark as duplicate, or copy rogermue's answer here ?

Comment: @ThomasFrancois Mark it as a duplicate, so we can keep all the answers in one place (easier to find, easier to maintain). The SE analog of the "DRY principle".

Comment: Check out this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0u8KUgUqprw